# How to design the database tables and relationships

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I was creating a system for its purchases and transactions and initially thought the db would needed to be look like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIciA.jpg

But after getting into the system

- The products from the suppliers are needed to be bought time to time
- The same product can be get from different suppliers.

So I changed the db to this way.

I'm still figuring out is this the best approach. And also is the product_purchase and order_products tables are many to many tables?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQO5W.jpg

Comment: i would suggest getting a beter user case from you customer and let him/her describe what the program should do or how they handle the process on paper or excel.. Ask for examples .. Then you can start designing the database to match real live as close as possible.. In the Netherlands Fully Communication Oriented Information Modeling ([FCO-IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FCO-IM))  is (pretty) populair to convert user cases into databases.

Comment: Write the `SELECTs` -- this will help you debug the schema.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to study about entity relationship model and all the phases of a database design (requirements, conceptual, logic, implementation). A wrong database design will influence negatively all the software that will be based on it in terms of performance and architecture.