# How to design the purchases and product data in database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to create a product order and purchase system.

The system has **products, product_purchase, purchases** tables to insert data on product purchases from suppliers. In a one purchase several products can be purchased. The quantity and unit prices are included in product_purchase table.

When a customer buy one or several products, the products quantity is decreased from **product_purchase** table. And the order details are stored in **orders table and order_products**.

Firstly I thought product_purchase table is gonna be a many to many pivot table. But as the product quantities are decreased from product_purchase table, cant it be called a pivot table? Or my approach is wrong?

Comment: Your other question [How to design the database tables and relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56825072/how-to-design-the-database-tables-and-relationships) seams to be related?

Comment: Hi. I thought users will understand the question this way rather than the old one. Because the resources to the question were in a separate website.